# Any Course/Lecture videos on Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices

I am planning to read some design patterns and I took the book on "design patterns in C++' by gang of four. However, I am not really some one who reads book and prefers reading slides/watching course lectures and then apply and read the book. I cannot find any course lecture videos on net(yeah, its not that important a course as algo/OS). Any one know any course website, preferably on C++

Comment: I know you said you're not one for reading, but check out http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124 . It's not your typical programming book.

Comment: Note that the GoF book is *not* a book on design patterns, it's a book *of* design patterns, a catalog if you will. Reading it to learn about design patterns is about as useful as reading a phone book to learn about human sociology. The GoF book is for looking up a pattern, *after* you already understand design patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Well, it's not a course, but...***

[C++ Programming/Code/Design Patterns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns) looks like a good book to look at. It is a book from Wikibooks (by Wikimedia).

***If you want a course...***

Another thing to look at might be [Design Patterns Course by Sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com/design-patterns-video). It has 97 lessons (7 hours) and includes 2 great books in the price. The only major con is that it is currently $49.95. But if you ask me, that's a good price for two books and 7 hours worth of video.

***Finally...***

Take a look at [the Design Patterns tag on Dimecasts.](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/Design%20Patterns) You might be able to find something there.

***Finally...Finally...***

[This question has been asked on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048973/design-patterns-video-tutorial) There are some great answers there, so take a look at that too.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly Microsoft stuff but I like the video training at http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=patterns-library.  They have a free trial.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have posted, I've always found dnrTV to be a fairly interesting: it's basically a screencast with a host and a special guest for each episode.  They generally work through some concepts and do some actual coding, which helps a lot when you are new to concepts.

(Unfortunately, they focus on .Net... but for design patterns this shouldn't matter - most design patterns are language agnostic, and the difficulty is understanding why and where they are useful.  Specific implementations can be looked up in minutes.)

They have a number of episodes dealing with design patterns - here is the [first one](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=63), and their [archives page](http://www.dnrtv.com/archives.aspx).  It's been a while, so I can't really remember what they cover in those episodes.  In general though, they aren't bad, and it's fun to see some sharp people's opinions and toolsets.

Comment: JP Boodhoo's videos are worth taking a look at.